# Appending data to an excel file in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

I have to append data to an already existing Excel file in node.js. So now i am using the `xlsx-writestream` package and the following code

```
var XLSXWriter = require('xlsx-writestream');
  var writer = new XLSXWriter('mySpreadsheet.xlsx', {});
  writer.getReadStream().pipe(fs.createWriteStream('transactions.xlsx'));

    writer.addRow({
      "description": "sdgsdg",
      "amount": 2000
    });
```

But its creating a new excel file,not appending to the existing file.  Please share your ideas.Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find out how to do it??

Comment: Thanks subburaj for your reply. I need to write to an existing xlsx file and currently only way i found is using file stream. No pre-built module is helpful. And that way i can only write to csv. Tried writing to xlsx but it gets corrupted. Maybe i dont know the seperator for xlsx, like for csv it is comma. :(

Comment: @sunny thanks.. So whats the solution for this? We can't do this??

Comment: Looks like we both are facing the same issue on same day. :) I am trying very hard. Will post the solution if I find.

Comment: sure..if if find something from my side i will post it..

Comment: @sunny Did you tried for separator as #?

Comment: @sunny Can you post the code what you have tried using file stream?

Comment: Guys, I know I'm asking a bit late, but have you find any solution for this problem? I'm facing with the same thing. I have to create an excel for Mssql exporter script wrote by an other guy and I cannot do with the existing modules.

Answer (score -1):

please refer the following page https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But the above will also create a new Excel not append to the existing Sheet..

Comment: Did you find any solution for this yet ?